# singleton при работе с базой данных

Tags: база-данных, любой-язык, singleton, шаблон-одиночка

Подскажите пожалуйста, если при работе с базой данных использовать паттерн Singleton, вызывать постоянно instance этого обьекта и работать с ним (делать выборки, update и т.д.) , то как поступать с методами например db.close() или db.dispose() для закрытия соединения. Немного непонятно, конкретно по Singleton с бд, в этом обьекте будет жить только создание обьекта, или будет вечный коннект к базе? Или там на уровне пулов? Если можно примеры?Есть не понимания как счетчик max_connection работает в таком случае, если соединение одно, то как блокировки не блокировки дб срабатывают!Как со скоростью ответа на клиент это влияет, нежели по классическому способу?

Comment: `если при работе с базой данных использовать паттерн Singleton` зачем?

Comment: @AntonSorokin а чего c# то убрали? )

Comment: @tym32167 `db.close()` как то не похоже на C#

Comment: db.close() - это так, абстрактно) пример как на камом либо языке было б по синтаксису)))

Comment: @AntonSorokin зато вот это похоже `db.dispose()` )

Comment: @tym32167 зато в java есть `db.close` а в c# нет. Так что java похожее.
UPD: а, не, там `connection`. Но все равно `close`

Comment: @AntonSorokin ну, [connection.Close()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close?view=netframework-4.8) есть и в c# ))

Comment: В принципе не важно в каком шаблоне вы работаете с БД, если соблюдаете механизмы, описанные в её документации. Шаблон накладывает ограничения на ваш код, т.е. вы должны его организовать таким способом, чтобы он функционировал и работал так, как вам нужно. Посмотрите примеры типа [этого](http://tiny.cc/5e819y) или других, где вам будут разъяснены основные моменты.В любом случае, перед обращением к БД вам нужно будет проверять состояние связи с ней.

Comment: в c# вам нет никакой необходимости делать контекст БД одиночкой. С подключениями тоже будет всё хорошо - для них есть [пул подключений](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.4.php)

Comment: Не нужно ставить метки всех подряд языков, ставьте только относящиеся к сути вопроса. Если вопрос касается какого-то стандартного API для работы с БД, скажем ODBC, поставьте его метку.